# Should I account for email opens when modeling link clicks embedden in the email?

Tags: predictive-models, conditional-probability, generative-models, marketing

I'm trying to build a model that predicts whether an email recipient will click on a link inside an email. As input, it takes member-related email click/open/unsubscribe history, as well as that member's history of engagement with similar links.

The key part in my mind is that a member must open the email to even have the chance to click on a link. That is, $$P(\text{click link}) = P(\text{click link}|\text{open email})P(\text{open email}).$$

To me, this implies I need to build 2 models that estimate the quantities on the RHS, which can then be multiplied. However, my colleagues and I are wondering if building 2 models is worth the squeeze and if we can instead just build one model that ignores the concept of email opens entirely. The business use case to this problem is sort of a "recommendation engine" where we rank different links by decreasing click probability in order to personalize emails to recipients. So I'm wondering if there are any serious statistical problems we would cause by ignoring email opens. I'm not totally sure if there are and how to know / test if so.

Any thoughts?